# Interior and closure of $n^3$ in the topology on $\mathbb Z$ generated by bi-infinite arithmetic progressions

Tags: general-topology, number-theory

Consider the topology on the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by the collection of all bi-infinite arithmetic progressions

$$\mathscr{B} = \{A_{a,d} \mid d\in \mathbb{N}, 0 \le a < d\}$$

$$A_{a,d} = \{a + dn \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Compute the closure and interior of $C = \{ n^3 \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

So... (I think) the set $C$ is neither open or closed. And I can't think of any open set (arithmetic progression) that would lie inside $0, 1, 8, 27, 64$, etc, so is the interior empty? I'm not confident about that....

I have no idea about the closure, but I know that all closed sets are open in this topology, so is it asking the intersection of all arithmetic progressions that contain the integers cubed?

Comment: If you look at my edits you might learn something about proper use of $\TeX$.

Comment: sorry, i just started using it last week.

Comment: My habitual assumption that people who know some math use $\LaTeX$ all the time must be somewhat less than the whole truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in this topology, it is not true that all closed sets are open in this topology. For example, every open set is infinite, but the singleton set $\{0\}$ is closed, as it is the complement of the open set
$$
\bigcup_{d=1}^\infty \bigcup_{a=1}^{d-1} A_{a,d} = \mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}.
$$
In fact, every finite set is closed.

Second, the set of cubes is $\{ \dots, -64, -27, -8, -1, 0, 1, 8, 27, 64, \dots\}$ - you left out the negative ones.

The set of cubes does in fact have empty interior. Showing this is equivalent to showing: every arithmetic progression contains a non-cube. This can be done in several ways; perhaps the easiest way is noting that the cubes get farther and farther apart, so eventually they can't contain two consecutive integers at distance $d$ from each other.

I believe the set of cubes is a closed set. Showing this is equivalent to showing that its complement is open, which is equivalent to: given any non-cube $k$, there exists $d>0$ such that none of the numbers in $A_{k,d}$ are cubes. In other words, if $k$ is a non-cube, then there exists a $d$ such that $k$ is not a cube modulo $d$. I think this is true, but it's not trivial as far as I can tell right now.

Comment: ah, I wasn't thinking. all open sets in this topology are closed, not the other way around. thank you for your thorough answer!

Comment: No, that's not right either. The same example shows that $\mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$ is open but not closed. (In fact, "all open sets are closed" and "all closed sets are open" are equivalent statements.) It is true that any bi-infinite arithmetic progression is both open and closed; but you can take arbitrary unions of opens sets, but only finite unions of closed sets; so that fact doesn't extend to the entire topology. (I suggest going back to the first sentence of your post and thinking carefully about what it means for a topology to be "defined by" a collection of sets.)

Answer (score 2):

A small supplement to Greg Martin's answer. As is shown in that answer, to prove that the set of cubes is closed is the same as to prove the following: for each non-cube $k$ there exists $d > 0$ such that $A_{k,d}$ contains no cubes.

This is quite simple. Since $k$ is not a cube, there exists a prime $p$ such that $k = lp^m$, where $p$ doesn't divide $l$ and $3$ doesn't divide $m$. Now just take $d = p^{m+1}$.

Consider an arbitrary number $x = k + nd$ from set $A_{k,d}$. Note that
$$
x = lp^m + np^{m+1} = p^m(l + np).
$$
$p^m$ divides $x$, but $p^{m+1}$ doesn't divide $x$. Since $m$ is not a multiple of $3$, it follows that $x$ is not a cube. Done.